# Trouble installing R and R studio in Elementary OS 5.0 Juno

Tags: software-installation, r, rstudio

I am attempting to install R and R Studio on Elementary OS 5.0 Juno. and after a few install methods, and attempting to remove previous packages and start with a fresh install, I am still getting the following error, can anyone please tell me what my next steps are?

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.1-3disco) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.6.1-3disco) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.6.1-3disco) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: For ElementaryOS, consider posting on [elementaryos.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using eOS Juno and this is based on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic. I can see in the errors that you try to use a version for Disco, which is Ubuntu 19.xx. So, please use the correct version.

If you have no experience with the different packages, maybe you should give a try to Anaconda. There you can install R and RStudio also and the tool will choose the correct version for you.

Just for your interest:
[How to create an R environment in Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/navigator/tutorials/create-r-environment/)

Comment: I was able to get r-base installed using the bionic version. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: As Elementary OS is based on Ubuntu, perhaps this script for installing Rstudio on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS may be of use: https://gist.github.com/ElToro1966/999f1c8ca51a75648dd587a3170e4335